# is the 'is' keyword in python a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, methods, operator-keyword

I am attempting to understand under what definition the 'is' keyword in Python falls under.

In the course I am taking, the instructor puts great emphasis on the difference between functions and method (class functions).
When asked, the instructor said its a function and referenced me to Python's Operator class and it's 'is_' method (which is simply a method to allow easy use of an operator, and not even the referred keyword).

```py
a is b
operator.is_(a,b)
```

I find myself struggling with the answer I have been given.
I would greatly appreciate it if you could, based on my instructors emphasis on functions and methods, explain if 'is' falls in any of them.
If not, what is the right way to view it?

Comment: Keywords are not functions. They are not methods either.

Comment: `operator` is a *module*, not a class. And `operator.is_` is a function, not a method.

Comment: There's an [`operator.is_()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.is_) function in the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#module-operator) module. Note the trailing underscore on `is_` which prevents it being interpreted as the keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [`is`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not) (as in `a is b`) is an *operator*. Specifically, a binary operator - because it takes two objects (`a` and `b` in the example) as input.

  What makes operators different from functions is the syntax - the two *operands* go on either side of the *operator*. If `is` were a function, it would be invoked like `is(a, b)`.
- [`operator.is_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.is_) is a *function* that takes two arguments (let's call them `a` and `b`) as input and returns `a is b`. It is the *functional equivalent* of the `is` operator. (The [documentation of the `operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) is even titled "Standard operators as functions".)

  Further, `operator.is_` is **not** a method. `operator` is a *module*, not a class, and `is_` is a function defined in that module.

Comment: This ^. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 1):

The `is` operator checks whether both the operands refer to the same object or not. It compares identities.
Whereas `==` compares the values of both the operands and checks for value equality. It compares by checking for equality.

Following is an easy example:

```
# [] is an empty list

list1 = [] 
list2 = [] 
list3 = list1 

if (list1 == list2): 
    print("True") 
else: 
    print("False")

if (list1 is list2): 
    print("True") 
else: 
    print("False") 

if (list1 is list3): 
    print("True") 
else:     
    print("False")
```

The output should be like the following:

```
True
False
True
```

- In the example you provided:
- in `a is b`, `is` is an **operator**
- in `operator.is()`
- `operator` is a **module**
- `is()` is the **function** defined in the `operator` module.